# Why consumer hangs while consuming messages from Kafka on DC/OS using Client API for Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, dcos

I installed Kafka on DC/OS (Mesos) cluster on AWS. Enabled three brokers and created a topic called "topic1".

```
dcos kafka topic create topic1 --partitions 3 --replication 3
```

Then I wrote a Producer class to send messages and a Consumer class to receive them.

```
public class Producer {
    public static void sendMessage(String msg) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Map<String, Object> producerConfig = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("setting Producerconfig.");
        producerConfig.put("bootstrap.servers", 
                "172.16.20.207:9946,172.16.20.234:9125,172.16.20.36:9636");

        ByteArraySerializer serializer = new ByteArraySerializer();
        System.out.println("Creating KafkaProcuder");
        KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerConfig, serializer, serializer);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String msgstr = msg + i;
            byte[] message = msgstr.getBytes();
            ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<>("topic1", message);
            System.out.println("Sent:" + msgstr);
            kafkaProducer.send(record);
        }
        kafkaProducer.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        sendMessage("Kafka test message 2/27 3:32");
    }

}

public class Consumer {
    public static String getMessage() {
        Map<String, Object> consumerConfig = new HashMap<>();
        consumerConfig.put("bootstrap.servers", 
                "172.16.20.207:9946,172.16.20.234:9125,172.16.20.36:9636");
        consumerConfig.put("group.id", "dj-group");
        consumerConfig.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        consumerConfig.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        ByteArrayDeserializer deserializer = new ByteArrayDeserializer();
        KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerConfig, deserializer, deserializer);

        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("topic1"));
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
            System.out.println(records.count() + " of records received.");
            for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : records) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(record.value()));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getMessage();
    }
}
```

First I ran `Producer` on the cluster to send messages to `topic1`. However when I ran `Consumer`, it couldn't receive anything, just hang.

`Producer` is working since I was able to get all the messages by running the shell script that came with Kafka install

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper master.mesos:2181/dcos-service-kafka --topic topic1 --from-beginning
```

But why can't I receive with `Consumer`? This [post](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/11) suggests group.id with old offset might be a possible cause. I only create group.id in the consumer not the producer. How do I config the offset for this group?

Comment: To make sure, the group.id is not an issue, use `kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning()`

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Should I delete `consumerConfig.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");` then? Where should I add this line, after subscribing? Still not getting anything after adding this.

Comment: Try to use a longer timeout when invoking poll and are there any exceptions thrown in the logs on the server/client side?

Comment: It depends on you overall pattern. "auto.offset.reset" is only applied if there are not committed offsets found while `seekToBeginnig()` ignores any committed offsets. Thus, on startup, you might get different behavior depending if there are committed offsets of not. For example, if you have a container environment, and a container fails and gets restarted, you might want to resume where you left of -- thus, `seekToBeginning()` might not be the behavior you want.

Comment: @amethystic Changed poll timeout to 1000 and still the same. No exception thrown. Nothing gets printed out. It just hangs.

Comment: How long did you wait for the consumer to read data? Do you call poll() over and over again (your code seems to call poll only once?). Maybe decreasing `metadata.max.age.ms` helps.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I am writing a test to check if Kafka works. All it does is send a number messages and see if it receives that many messages. Therefore, I need to resume from the last committed offset and only poll once.

Comment: But how can you be sure, that a single `poll()` return all messages you wrote? There is guarantee about how many messages will be returned (as far as I know)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out, `kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("topic1"));` is causing `poll()` to hang. According to [Kafka Consumer does not receive messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414308/kafka-consumer-does-not-receive-messages)
, there are two ways to connect to a topic, `assign` and `subscribe`. After I replaced `subscribe` with the lines below, it started working.

```
    TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("topic1", 0);
    List<TopicPartition> tps = Arrays.asList(tp);
    kafkaConsumer.assign(tps);
```

However the output shows arrays of numbers which is not expected (Producer sent Strings). But I guess this is a separate issue.

Comment: The so-called "separate issue" is that you're receiving bytes (since Kafka processes bytes under the hood). You should use a deserializer, e.g. `key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer`  for key and a separate one for values. See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/ (but I can't find the exact page for SerDe).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Thanks for the explanation. Saved me another post

Comment: It may still hang with `assign` if your topic has multiple partitions. Fix this by adding every partition to the list, not just `0`, after finding out how many there are with `./kafka-topics --describe`.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you gracefully shutdown your consumer:

```
consumer.close()
```

---

**TLDR**

When you have two consumers running with the same *group id* Kafka won't assign the same partition of your topic to both.

If you repeatedly run an app that spins up a consumer with the same *group id* and you don't shut them down gracefully, Kafka will take a while to consider a consumer from an earlier run as dead and reassign his partition to a new one.

If new messages come to that partition and it's never assigned to your new consumer, the consumer will never see the messages.

To debug:

- How many partition your topic has:
  `./kafka-topics --zookeeper <host-port> --describe <topic>`
- How far have your group consumed from each partition:
  `./kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <host-port> --describe --group <group-id>`

If you already have your partitions stuck on stale consumers, either wipe the state of your Kafka or use a new group id.