# Kafka consumer api failed to subscribe to topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using simple Kafka client API. As far as I know there are two ways to consumer messages, subscribe to a topic and assign partition to consumer.

However the first method does not work. Consumer `poll()` would hang forever. It only works with `assign`.

```
    // common config for consumer
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrap);

    config.put("group.id", KafkaTestConstants.KAFKA_GROUP);
    config.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    config.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    config.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    config.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    StringDeserializer deserializer = new StringDeserializer();
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(config, deserializer, deserializer);

    // subscribe does not work, poll() hangs
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(KafkaTestConstants.KAFKA_TOPIC));
```

Here is the code that works by assigning the partition.

```
    // assign works
    TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition(KafkaTestConstants.KAFKA_TOPIC, 0);
    List<TopicPartition> tps = Arrays.asList(tp);
    consumer.assign(tps);
```

Since I'd like to utilize the auto commit feature which is supposed to only work with consumer group management according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701394/why-doesnt-offset-get-updated-when-messages-are-consumed-in-kafka). Why does not `subscribe()` work?

Comment: It is not possible to use both manual partition assignment with assign(Collection) and group assignment with subscribe.

Comment: @amethystic I don't mean to make BOTH to work. Just trying to get `subscribe` working is all.

Comment: Could you remove `consumer.assign(tps)` then and retry ?

Comment: @amethystic Sorry about the confusion. The last two blocks of code don't exist at the same time. Just trying to say the `subscribe` method does not work while the last three lines work

Comment: What version of Kafka do you use on server side and client side? And you could also try a new group.id to rerun the program, checking whether there are any exceptions thrown on the server/client side?

Comment: @amethystic the kafka client version is 0.10.2.0. The kafka version on the server is 0.1.0. I had UUID in group id originally, it seemed to work by getting all the messages every time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137718/discussion-between-amethystic-and-ddd).

Comment: Hi guys, I'm facing the same issue and I tried following the resolution of this in the chat, but regretfully I can't read Chinese. Could any of you please post which was the solution found? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JPS Essentially, use an older version of consumer instead. It's been a while and I don't remember how exactly this was resolved. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue.
I was using the kafka_2.12 jar version, when I downgrade it to kafka_2.11 it worked.