# Kafka Consumer API not subscribing using Java client

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka: 0.10.1.0 (Client & Server)
Java client.
Zookeeper: 3.4.6

**Setup**: Producer publishes messages. Sent messages on topic counted using `./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic TEST.TOPIC --time -1`

**Issue** Consumer when polled while subscribing doesn't work but if you manually assign() - it works. There had been a [separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707131/kafka-consumer-api-failed-to-subscribe-to-topic/43902454#43902454) on same question but no answer. It may be UUID issue but need more details as we are in evaluating phase and details would help.

Consumer Settings:
props.put("bootstrap.servers", servers);
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT);

```
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS);
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS);
    props.put("group.id", CONSUMER_GROUP_ID);
    props.put("key.deserializer", STRING_DESRIALIZER);
    props.put("value.deserializer", STRING_DESRIALIZER);
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
```

Comment: are you using the command line consumer? can you share the consumer configurations?

Comment: updated. I am using Java client (KafkaConsumer). When I use subscribe(topics) - doesn't work. assign(topicPartitions) - Works.

Comment: do you have the following property set in kafka properties? `etc/kafka/server.properties usually. listeners=PLAINTEXT://<ip>:<port>` This tells kafka to listen for consumers here in plaintext (vs ssl).

Comment: yes. _listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093_

Comment: @daniel - listeners property would be required by both subscribe() and assign() methods - correct? Is it possible that this proeprty is useful for only one mechanism?

Comment: Same version for both clients and servers?

Comment: Yes. Both versions are:  _0.10.1_

Comment: any more clues/hints?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with Version of Kafka.

Switched to 0.10.2.1 (server and client) and subscribe() worked flawlessly.